# Sorting problem in HashTable

Tags: java, sorting, hashtable

my problem is i have to parsed these values

```
Cijfercode 
Crypto 
Doorlopr 
Kruizword 
Woordzoker
Zweeds
```

from an xml file.but in xml they are in the alphabetical order same as above.but while using hashtable to retrive values (these values are not keys of this hashtable)it becomes the order

```
Cijfercode
Doorloper
Woordzoker
Zweeds
Kruizword
Crypto
```

why is is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [`LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) to maintain the order in which the elements where inserted, (or a `TreeMap` if you need some custom ordering, such as alphabetical, regardless of insertion order).

A `HashTable` does not preserve any order. Just like `Set` it's an *unordered* data structure.

Comment: ok but firsly values are added  alphabetical order in the hashtable.

Comment: yep. Unfortunately that doesn't matter. It should work as you expect if you use a LinkedHashMap.

Comment: but retriving from hashtable order changes.

Comment: so ? If you are looking at retrieving elements in the same order it was inserted , you shouldnt be using an **unorderded** data structure , should you ?

Comment: LinkedHashMap maintains the order of the elements same as they we inserted; if that is what you want then use LinkedHashMap. If you want to get natural ordering of elements, say alphabetically, then TreeMap should be used.

Comment: Hi every one. i got a solution for sorting the hashtable elements .Here is the solution
 java.util.Vector vec =new java.util.Vector(hashtableList.keySet()); 
Collections.sort(vec);

Comment: I'd use `ArrayList` in favor of `Vector`. For this particular scenario however, you're probably better of just using a `TreeMap` anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

HashTable and HashMap both do not guarantee the ordering of it's elements. You should use TreeMap for such purposes.

Comment: Hi every one. i got a solution for sorting the hashtable elements .Here is the solution
 java.util.Vector vec =new java.util.Vector(hashtableList.keySet()); 
Collections.sort(vec);